# SlimDX, understanding how the window works

Tags: c#, slimdx

Okay i am trying to begin learning SlimDX, as i need probably need it for my application.

And as i don´t know DirectX, i am stuck very early with how a thing works.
And that is creating a render window, here is how the example shows, and i pretty much copy paste it.

```
            MessagePump.Run(form, () =>
        {
            // clear the render target to a soothing blue
            context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderTarget, new Color4(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f));

            // draw the triangle
            context.Draw(3, 0);
            swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
        });
```

Now i do understand it somehow, but what i don´t get, is "MessagePump.Run". This causes everything in the code to Pause.

And what i am trying to do, which is loading pictures constantly, won´t work if the code pauses when i open a window.

Answer (score 0):

Think i solved it myself, it creates it´s own loop, so i have to use it in a thread.